# Multiple forms in one page Formik

Tags: reactjs, typescript, formik, chakra-ui

Is is possible to have multiple formik forms in one page? I have 2 forms and Submit button is not working for any of them.

I tried refs but i couldnt fix the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
import { Formik, Form, Field } from "formik";

const Form1 = () => {
  const handleSubmit1 = (values) => {
    console.log("Form 1 submitted:", values);
  };

  return (
    <Formik initialValues={{}} onSubmit={handleSubmit1}>
      <Form>
        <Field name="field1" />
        <button type="submit">Submit Form 1</button>
      </Form>
    </Formik>
  );
};

const Form2 = () => {
  const handleSubmit2 = (values) => {
    console.log("Form 2 submitted:", values);
  };

  return (
    <Formik initialValues={{}} onSubmit={handleSubmit2}>
      <Form>
        <Field name="field2" />
        <button type="submit">Submit Form 2</button>
      </Form>
    </Formik>
  );
};

const MyComponent = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Form1 />
      <Form2 />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: How does useFormikContext work here? i.e. How does the context differentiate between Form1 and Form2? assuming I use useFormikContext in MyComponent

Comment: `useFormContext` will work only if it has a `<Formik>` component parent. So in this example it would not work inside `MyComponent`.